# No scoped proxy for SqlSessionTemplate with Spring JavaConfig

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-java-config, spring-mybatis

I am trying to make MyBatis Mappers serializable (kind of). To do so, I would simply want to wrap the `SqlSessionTemplate` (which is the non-serializable thing) via Java config into a scoped proxy...

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages={"com.example.mybatis.mappers"}, sqlSessionTemplateRef="sqlSession")
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession(final SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, since the scoped proxy for the SqlSessionTemplateseems to be created, but what's injected into the Mapper in the end is still a standard `SqlSessionTemplate` (and not the Proxy around it), which has somehow escaped the proxy. The problematic part seems to be this method from `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate`...

```
@Override
public <T> T getMapper(Class<T> type) {
    return getConfiguration().getMapper(type, this);
}
```

Of course, `this` here refers to the original `SqlSessionTemplate` object and not the Proxy around it.

Is there a way to force my scoped proxy into the mappers?

Of course, what works is to simply making the mappers themselves scoped proxies, but that seems to be less elegant and concise (and would require me to skip autoscanning for mappers and instead declare each mapper manually), so I would prefer making the problematic object a scoped proxy, since the `MapperProxy` itself is already Serializable and could be serialized - it just gets prevented by the `SqlSessionTemplate`.

Edit: Of course there's also the problem that SqlSessionTemplate doesn't come with a default contructor, which will also be a problem, but one at a time...